# PHP function to replace links found in RSS feed longer then x char

Tags: php, regex, parsing, url, rss

I have an RSS feed which I am parsing and in some pages of the feed there are very long URLs that break my page. For example, some are like this when you see them on the page.

> http://example.com/coolthings/893748662/photos/37774656-ID/another_dam_dir/MORESTUFF.php?id=7837839946HS67355

So because they used the actual URL for some of the links in the page instead of linking to some text about it I am left with crazy long URL-based links. I want a way to build some code into the parser that will automatically detect these crazy long links anywhere in the page content and maybe shorten them to something like `http://example.com/coolthings/`.

I would like some type of PHP function I can use that will scan through the page and shorten the crazy long URLs if they are found. I have looked all over and even tried to make something that can do this and have failed at the attempts.

I can use `preg_match_all` to find the URLs but can't seem to find a simple way of replacing them within the page.

The page is parsed via curl and SimpleXML and a few regexs. Ideas how I can do this greatly appreciated.

//Not Working attempt ...
This will find the crazy long urls but then they must be replaced in the page with the short version and i cant seem to make that part of my idea work. I also wrote a func cutto_mid to trim at middle. I will use that when i can get this link replace code to work.

```
function short_link($text){
$regex = "a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+"."(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>";
preg_match_all ("/$regex/i", $text, &$matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
foreach($matches as $vars){     
if (strlen($vars) > '95'){
//return "<BR>".cutto_mid($vars, 20, 20, 50); //testing ...
return preg_replace("#$regex#i",'<a href="'.$vars .'">Replace W Short Link</a>', $text);
}
}
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you only want to truncate only links in the node values, not the `href` attribute values, right? So, you first need to parse HTML to get the texts containing links and then you can check if the links are too long and truncate at the 2nd slash. What code do you have? Please share.

Comment: does not have to be at the second slash that was just an example I actually wrote a func that will trunkit in the middle. but i need some way to get the link into my func from the parsed page. I will update my post with some code I was playing with.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Regular Expressions to parse HTML, especially not when you're already using an XML parser. Rather use XPath to fetch all anchors with an href, then test the length of their value. Something like this:

```
$links = $xml->xpath ("//a[@href]");
foreach ($links as &$l) {
    if (strlen ($l[0]) < CUTOFF)
        continue;

    $l[0] = substr ($l[0], 0, CUTOFF-3).'...';
}
```

Comment: Don't quite understand how that works, how will that replace the links on the page? remember it must mod the links from the page that are too long and replace them with the short version using the cut_middle func I wrote. the links will be within the pages from the feed, they will not be accessible as a sep channel. please show me how to use the code above in the scenario for which i need to use it.

Comment: I'm [http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php](passing by reference) in the loop. Which means that all the `$l` array does, is to point back at the relevant node in the original DOM. Afterwards its just to save, echo, or however you wish to utilize, the HTML.

Comment: Thanks but i can do that now even with my existing code, i need a func that I can work into my existing code, it has to find the long urls and replace them in the page itself i can already echo the long links found. I am not trying to save or echo anything as I can already do that, so that realy does not help me with my existing problem. my code can find the inks but not replace them in the page, I need a way to do that. i just used some regex code as that's what I was able to get working. but a better working solution is what im after.